# why are ip addresses overlapping in packet tracer? 202.101.99.192 overlaps with GigabitEthernet0/1

Tags: networking, router, ip

This is my router! the topology is one router connected to one pc on g0/1, on g0/0 its connected to a switch then connected to a pc. the whole network is 202.101.99.0/24, using VLSM we had to break it down first with 98 usable hosts so I decided for the IP address of the router for g0/0 I want to use 202.101.99.129 255.255.255.128., then I assigned the pc 202.101.99.130, I went to assign the IP address to the g0/0 and its saying theyre over lapping..why is this

```
bye>    
bye>enable    
bye#config t     
bye(config)#interface g0/1    
bye(config-if)#ip address 202.101.99.129 255.255.255.128    
bye(config-if)#no shutdown    
bye(config-if)#exit    
bye(config)#int g0/0    
bye(config-if)#ip address 202.101.99.161 255.255.255.224     
% 202.101.99.160 overlaps with GigabitEthernet0/1    
bye(config-if)#ip address 202.101.99.193 255.255.255.224    
% 202.101.99.192 overlaps with GigabitEthernet0/1   
bye(config-if)#ip address 202.101.99.163 255.255.255.128    
% 202.101.99.128 overlaps with GigabitEthernet0/1    
bye(config-if)#
```

Comment: btw for g0/0 I was using ip 202.101.99.161 255.255.255.224

Comment: [This two-part answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/53994/8499) explains how to do this and where you went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

For interface `g0/1` you're using the network `202.101.99.128 /25`. With this, the network address is `202.101.99.128`, the usable hosts range from `202.101.99.129-202.101.99.254`. Your broadcast address would be `202.101.99.255`.

For interface `g0/0` you assigned it `202.101.99.161` which is using the `202.101.99.160 /27` network. This overlaps with your previous network. Because as stated above, the `202.101.99.128 /25` network covers the ranges `.129-.254`.

By looking at the chart below, you can see that your first network takes up all of the addresses in the red box, ranging from `.128 - .255` In order to not have overlap, you would have to assign `g0/0` one of the network addresses in the green box.

If each network is supposed to have 98 usable hosts, your best option would be to use the `202.101.99.0 /25` and `202.101.99.128 /25` networks

[image]

Comment: TYSM, but I forgot to mention that the g0/0 has 30 usable hosts, idk if that changes anything

Comment: @user969645 it doesn't change the entire concept, but to reduce address gapping, I would assign `g0/1` with the network `202.101.99.0 /25`and `g0/0` with the network `202.101.99.128 /27`.

Comment: for some reason it tells me using 202.101.99.0 /25 is bad mask

Comment: @user969645 that's the network address, which would show up in the routing table on the router. Assign `202.101.99.1-.127` to interfaces and PC's on that network.

Comment: thank you! it makes a lot more sense now